# What causes frames to be dropped/lost when playing videos with higher resolution on VLC?

Tags: windows-7, vlc-media-player, youtube, video-streaming

I noticed on this [Battlefield Hardline Trailer at 60fps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3ny9zIckP0&index=1&list=PLbsGxdAPhjv9UrLo19pS8teoRKj7funAy), about half the frames are dropped on my laptop playing it at 1920x1080 60fps. If play it 1280x720 60fps, no frames are dropped. What causes the frames to be dropped or lost?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Graphics are extremely calculation intensive.  Often these calculations are farmed out to special functions on graphics cards - which is why some graphics cards cost more then PC's and are used by high end gamers.

The simplified bottom line though is that the number of calculations at 1920x1080 is more then 4 times the calculations at 1280 x 720  (depending on what is being calculated it could be a LOT more then 4 times), so your hardware can't calculate fast enough and drops frames so as that things can work.

Answer (score 1):

Your CPU and/or GPU are not fast enough to decode the video at that resolution and/or frame rate.  There is a check box for GPU acceleration you can check in VLC and that might help.

Also if your video is h264/h265 encoded at 1080p GPU acceleration is **required**.

Comment: It is interesting that my CPU is only 2% usage during playback on vlc*32 which is baffling.

Comment: @sunk818 Either you have GPU accelerated turn on, or your video card is new enough to detect an automatically take over decoding.

Comment: Yet it drops the frames. I take it decoding is only done by the gpu or CPU, but not both?

Comment: @sunk818 It depends on the software, there is nothing, aside from the complexity of the task, stopping a programmer from programming it to use both.  There is a possibility there is lag in your internet connection also.